# How to create an indicator column to indicate specific change from a previous entry in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

**The Situation:**

I currently have a have a dataframe of clients, which is sorted by `CLIENT_ID and CURRENT_DATE_STATUS`.`CLIENT_ID` as shown below:

| CLIENT_ID | CURRENT_DATE_STATUS | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10002 | 2017-07-21 | STARTED |
| 10002 | 2017-07-21 | STARTED |
| 10002 | 2018-07-01 | CHURNED |
| 10002 | 2018-07-01 | CHURNED |
| 10002 | 2019-01-01 | RESTARTED |
| 11811 | 2019-08-15 | STARTED |
| 11811 | 2019-08-15 | STARTED |
| 11811 | 2019-12-31 | RESTARTED |
| 22101 | 2020-03-11 | STARTED |
| 22101 | 2020-03-11 | STARTED |
| 22101 | 2020-03-11 | STARTED |
| 22101 | 2020-11-01 | CHURNED |
| 22300 | 2018-05-06 | STARTED |
| 22300 | 2018-05-06 | STARTED |

**The Question:**

How can I create an indicator `Boolean 1 or 0` column which indicates:

- If the previous `STATUS` entry has changed to either `CHURNED or RESTARTED` for each `CLIENT_ID`.

**The Objective:**

The resultant dataframe would be as shown below:

| CLIENT_ID | CURRENT_DATE_STATUS | STATUS | STOPPED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10002 | 2017-07-21 | STARTED | 0 |
| 10002 | 2017-07-21 | STARTED | 0 |
| 10002 | 2018-07-01 | CHURNED | 1 |
| 10002 | 2018-07-01 | CHURNED | 0 |
| 10002 | 2019-01-01 | RESTARTED | 1 |
| 11811 | 2019-08-15 | STARTED | 0 |
| 11811 | 2019-08-15 | STARTED | 0 |
| 11811 | 2019-12-31 | RESTARTED | 1 |
| 22101 | 2020-03-11 | STARTED | 0 |
| 22101 | 2020-03-11 | STARTED | 0 |
| 22101 | 2020-03-11 | STARTED | 0 |
| 22101 | 2020-11-01 | CHURNED | 1 |
| 22300 | 2018-05-06 | STARTED | 0 |
| 22300 | 2018-05-06 | STARTED | 0 |

**The Code used to generate said dataframe:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'CLIENT_ID':[10002,10002,10002,10002,10002,11811,11811,11811,22101,22101,22101,22101,22300,22300],
'CURRENT_DATE_STATUS':['2017-07-21','2017-07-21','2018-07-01','2018-07-01','2019-07-01','2019-08-15','2019-08-15','2019-12-31','2020-03-11','2020-03-11','2020-03-11','2020-11-01','2018-05-06','2018-05-06'],
'STATUS':['STARTED','STARTED','CHURNED','CHURNED','RESTARTED','STARTED','STARTED','RESTARTED','STARTED','STARTED','STARTED','CHURNED','STARTED','STARTED']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare actual values for eqaul by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) with shifted per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) for not equal[`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html), chain by `&` for bitwise `AND` and last chain by `|` for bitwise `OR` with casting to integers:

```
s = df.groupby('CLIENT_ID')['STATUS'].shift()
m1 = df['STATUS'].eq('RESTARTED') & s.ne('RESTARTED')
m2 = df['STATUS'].eq('CHURNED') & s.ne('CHURNED')

df['STOPPED'] = (m1 | m2).astype(int)
print (df)
    CLIENT_ID CURRENT_DATE_STATUS     STATUS  STOPPED
0       10002          2017-07-21    STARTED        0
1       10002          2017-07-21    STARTED        0
2       10002          2018-07-01    CHURNED        1
3       10002          2018-07-01    CHURNED        0
4       10002          2019-07-01  RESTARTED        1
5       11811          2019-08-15    STARTED        0
6       11811          2019-08-15    STARTED        0
7       11811          2019-12-31  RESTARTED        1
8       22101          2020-03-11    STARTED        0
9       22101          2020-03-11    STARTED        0
10      22101          2020-03-11    STARTED        0
11      22101          2020-11-01    CHURNED        1
12      22300          2018-05-06    STARTED        0
13      22300          2018-05-06    STARTED        0
```

Another solution is compare shifted values by previous and then if match by list in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), last chain by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
m3 = df.groupby('CLIENT_ID')['STATUS'].shift().ne(df['STATUS'])
m4 = df['STATUS'].isin(["CHURNED", "RESTARTED"])

df['STOPPED'] = (m3 & m4).astype(int)
print (df)

    CLIENT_ID CURRENT_DATE_STATUS     STATUS  STOPPED
0       10002          2017-07-21    STARTED        0
1       10002          2017-07-21    STARTED        0
2       10002          2018-07-01    CHURNED        1
3       10002          2018-07-01    CHURNED        0
4       10002          2019-07-01  RESTARTED        1
5       11811          2019-08-15    STARTED        0
6       11811          2019-08-15    STARTED        0
7       11811          2019-12-31  RESTARTED        1
8       22101          2020-03-11    STARTED        0
9       22101          2020-03-11    STARTED        0
10      22101          2020-03-11    STARTED        0
11      22101          2020-11-01    CHURNED        1
12      22300          2018-05-06    STARTED        0
13      22300          2018-05-06    STARTED        0
```